# Why does a reference to a value in previous row throw this Expression.Error?

Tags: excel, powerquery, m

I am trying to perform an operation in Excel using Powerquery.

I want to remove contacts in a list if they are connected to a certain CompanyID but are listed with a different CompanyName.

The fist step is to filter them out by comparing to the row above. They are always listed consecutively.

Next step is to remove all rows containing the value delete in the delete column but unfortunately I do not get to that step.

I have looked at [this post](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5577b086-1d84-4b7e-9bed-59f15b01a8b0/how-can-i-do-calculation-based-on-nextprior-row-in-power-query?forum=powerquery) and have tried with the following code:

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"Added index", "Delete", each if [CustomerID]= #"Added index"{[ContactID]-1}[CustomerID] and [CompanyName]<> #"Added index"{[ContactID]-1}[CompanyName] then "delete" else null)
```

But I get this error:

```
There were too many elements in the enumeration to complete the operation
```

I have googled the error and it seems to be connected with duplicated column names but I do not have any of those.

Please help!

Comment: Are you adding this step right after the `Added index` step? Or are there any steps in between? Post the code starting from the `Added index` step. The statement you posted works fine for me, so there must be something in the data.

Comment: Thx @teylyn! That turned me in the right direction. Just as you suspected there are several steps in between. 'Added Index' and 'Add Column'. I do not want to post the complete code since there are too much sensitive info. It would take too long to edit them out, and also risking typos in the code.

Comment: I will try to explain the steps that was causing the error. After creating the index column I created a custom column named CustomerID and used the index column to generate a number serie starting from 10000. 10001, 10002, 10003 and so on. I then removed the index column. Next I used the code in the original post to try to reference to the row above using the CustomerID column. That's when the error occured.

Comment: After adding a new Index column the code worked as intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have any steps after the `#"Added Index"` that manipulate the data, you need to be aware that the current step will refer to the data as it appears in the `#"Added Index"` step. Any manipulations that you performed after the `#"Added index"` step will not be available to the statement you posted.

You may want to adjust your posted step to use the latest representation of your data instead of `#"Added index"`.

If `#"Added index"` is the most recent step in your M code, the statement runs fine, so the problem is that the data is manipulated in the steps in between. Adjust the statement to refer to the most recent data step instead of `#"Added index"`.

Comment: Thanks alot, @teylyn!